# Subclassing HashMap in Scala, working around type erasure

Tags: scala, type-erasure

Let's say that for some good reason I want a generic HashMap that contains all types of objects.  I also want to push any unsightly `instanceof`-like type checks into the data structure.  To this end, a method like `getAs[T <: Any](key: String): Option[T]` would be nice to have.

```
class State extends HashMap[String, Any] {

  override def +[T >: Any](elem: (String, T)): State = super.+(elem)
  override def -(key: String): State = super.-(key)

  def getAs[T](key: String): Option[T] = {
    super.get(key) match {
      case s: Some[T] => s
      case _ => None
    }
  }

}
object State extends HashMap[String, Any] {
  override def empty: State = super.empty
}
```

I also have the following implicit conversion defined in the package object:

```
implicit def fromHashMap(m: HashMap[String, Any]): State = m.asInstanceOf[State]
```

When I compile the above code I get the following type erasure warning:

```
State.scala:10: warning: non variable type-argument T in type pattern Some[T] is
unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
case s: Some[T] => s
        ^
```

This is unfortunate, since the entire purpose of that statement if to check the type!

In this case, do I have an option other than resorting to the experimental Manifest features?  Moreover, is there a better basic approach to accomplish this?

**Edit:**

I got this working with using Manifests.  I was helped along greatly by [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094173/how-do-i-get-around-type-erasure-on-scala-or-why-cant-i-get-the-type-parameter) on Stackoverflow.  However, I am still curious if there is a cleaner way anyone can recommend.

**Double Edit:**

Here is the current version of this.  Manifests solved my immediate issues.  However, a major change I made was to make the State class a wrapper for a Map.  In doing so, I lost the advantages of inheritance (i.e. now I have to explicitly expose each map method I need *a la* `keySet` below.

```
class State(
  map: HashMap[String, (Manifest[_], Any)] = 
    scala.collection.immutable.HashMap.empty[String, (Manifest[_], Any)]
) extends java.io.Serializable {

  def +[T <: Any](elem: (String, T))(implicit m: Manifest[T]): State =
    State(map.+((elem._1, (m, elem._2))))

  def -(key: String): State = State(map.-(key))

  def keySet = map.keySet

  def getAs[T](key: String)(implicit m : Manifest[T]): Option[T] = {
    map.get(key) match {
      case Some((om: Manifest[_], o: Any)) =>
        if (om <:< m) Some(o.asInstanceOf[T]) else None
      case _ => None
    }
  }

}

object State {
  def apply() = new State()
  def apply(map: HashMap[String, (Manifest[_], Any)]) = new State(map)
  def empty = State()
}
```

Thanks to everyone who has looked at this so far.

### Update for Scala 2.10:

See the current implementation of `State` using `ClassTag` and friends [here on GitHub](https://github.com/EnMAS/EnMAS-Framework/blob/master/enmas-core/src/main/scala/org/enmas/pomdp/State.scala).  I plan to update it to use `TypeTag`s once `TypeCreator`s are serializable.

Comment: A minor mistake in your code, matching on  Some[T] would likely not work even without erasure. In all likelihood, get in any Map[A,B] impl would return a new Some[B], so in your case, it would be Some[Any] whatever the actual type of the value inside. So without type erasure, the proper clause would be case Some(t: T) => Some(t).

Comment: Looks like the github link is broken

Answer (score 2):

Note that while

```
case s: Some[T]
```

Doesn't work because `Some`'s type parameter is erased, this is different:

```
case s @ Some(_: T)
```

In this case, it doesn't work because `T` is a type parameter itself. While this does not make a difference in your case (no, there's no way other than manifests), consider the following:

```
case s: Some[Int]      // erased
case s @ Some(_: Int)  // not erased
```

Comment: Could you point me toward some documentation on the `@` operator?  I have not come across that yet.

Comment: what would `case Some(_ : T)` do?

Comment: @ConnorDoyle Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359014/scala-operator).

Comment: @Raphael It will verify that the value can be extracted with `Some.unapply` (or `Some.unapplySeq`, if it existed), and, if so, check the class of the extracted value against `T`. If `T` is erased, it will just compare it against `Object`, which is always true (even `AnyVal` subtypes get boxed).

Comment: Thanks. I think this is curious: type parameter is not erased if the matched expression is assigned a name, but is if not.

Comment: @Raphael Type parameter is always checked. When you do `S @ Some(_: T)` you are not checking that `s` is of type `Some[T]`. You are checking that `s` is a `Some` whose content has _type_ `T` (not type parameter).