# What does `var @ _*` signify in Scala

Tags: scala

I'm reviewing some Scala code trying to learn the language. Ran into a piece that looks like the following:

```
 case x if x startsWith "+" => 
          val s: Seq[Char] = x
          s match {
            case Seq('+', rest @ _*) => r.subscribe(rest.toString){ m => }
          }
```

In this case, what exactly is `rest @ _*` doing? I understand this is a `pattern match` for a Sequence, but I'm not exactly understanding what that second parameter in the Sequence is supposed to do.

Was asked for more context so I added the code block I found this in.

Comment: Please provide more context.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I was wrong - additional context was not necessary :)

Comment: See also [value binding](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2359365/298389). You case is actually composition of *value binding* with *varargs syntax sugar*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have come across `_*` before in the form of applying a Seq as varargs to some method/constructor, eg:

```
val myList = List(args: _*)
```

then this is the "unapply" (more specifically, search for "unapplySeq") version of this: take the sequence and convert back to a "varargs", then assign the result to `rest`.

Answer (score 2):

`x @ p` matches the pattern `p` and binds the result of the whole match to `x`. This pattern matches a `Seq` containing `'+'` followed by any number (`*`) of unnamed elements (`_`) and binds `rest` to a `Seq` of those elements.

Comment: Is `*` the name of an extractor, or is it syntactic?

Comment: What would be great also is some terminology I can google to see more examples/explanations. I tried searching 'pattern matching', but it doesn't go into extractors or anything similar.

Comment: @randombits I tried googling for "scala pattern match unapplySeq" and came up with [this link](http://daily-scala.blogspot.com.au/2009/09/extract-sequences-unapplyseq.html)

Comment: @Owen, it is syntactic feature related to varargs.