# Scala case match default value

Tags: scala

How can I get the default value in match case?

```
//Just an example, this value is usually not known
val something: String = "value"

something match {
    case "val" => "default"
    case _ => smth(_) //need to reference the value here - doesn't work
}
```

**UPDATE:** I see that my issue was not really understood, which is why I'm showing an example which is closer to the real thing I'm working on:

```
val db =    current.configuration.getList("instance").get.unwrapped()
            .map(f => f.asInstanceOf[java.util.HashMap[String, String]].toMap)
            .find(el => el("url").contains(referer))
            .getOrElse(Map("config" -> ""))
            .get("config").get match {
                case "" => current.configuration.getString("database").getOrElse("defaultDatabase")
                case _  => doSomethingWithDefault(_)
            }
```

Comment: Not sure, you mean this maybe? `case _ => smth(something)`

Comment: @DavidRiccitelli that `something` comes from a very long sequence of actions which is why I need another way to reference it

Comment: To understand better, are you trying to pass `something` to `smth` when `something` is not equal to `val`? (as an example)

Comment: Ok, you could split to make it also readable - as Martin O. says :-)

Comment: `val config = current.configuration.getList("instance").get.unwrapped()
            .map(f => f.asInstanceOf[java.util.HashMap[String, String]].toMap)
            .find(el => el("url").contains(referer))
            .getOrElse(Map("config" -> ""))
            .get("config").get` and then `config match ....`

Comment: @DavidRiccitelli For some reason (from examples I've seen) I thought that the point of functional programming is to do everything in one go, that is without creating intermediate variables?

Comment: nope it's not ... I'll try to get the speech from Martin Odersky where he specifically tells: "don't do one liners" :-)

Comment: @Caballero not necessarily, readability wins, always =)

Comment: There we go, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kkTFx3-duc8, minute 15 onwards "Don't pack too much as an expression".

Comment: I don't have a problem with the expr chain per se, but the cast is suspicious (as always), and I think the extra get can be avoided by flatmapping the result of the find and if you wind up with None, do the fallback at the end. That's just on principle of deferring the get as long as you can.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

```
something match {
    case "val" => "default"
    case default => smth(default)
}
```

It is not a keyword, just an alias, so this will work as well:

```
something match {
    case "val" => "default"
    case everythingElse => smth(everythingElse)
}
```

Comment: or if you don't need to use the variable, it can be anonymous:
case _ => doSomething

Comment: @JeroenKransen your proposition is exactly equals to what op started from

Comment: I didn't understand the valid question either. There was a similar recent question, How do I refer to _ in an anon function. Maybe it's like one of those optical illusion puzzles.

Answer (score 23):

The "_" in Scala is a love-and-hate syntax which could really useful and yet confusing.

In your example:

```
something match {
    case "val" => "default"
    case _ => smth(_) //need to reference the value here - doesn't work
}
```

the _ means, I don't care about the value, as well as the type, which means you can't reference to the identifier anymore.
  Therefore, smth(_) would not have a proper reference.
  The solution is that you can give the a name to the identifier like:

```
something match {
    case "val" => "default"
    case x => smth(x)
}
```

I believe this is a working syntax and x will match any value but not "val".

More speaking.  I think you are confused with the usage of underscore in map, flatmap, for example.

```
val mylist = List(1, 2, 3)
mylist map { println(_) }
```

Where the underscore here is referencing to the iterable item in the collection. 
Of course, this underscore could even be taken as:

```
mylist map { println }
```

Comment: Actually it is not only the Scala thing -- the underscode-for-things-I-don't care is used in SML, Clojure and some other languages.

Answer (score 3):

here's another option:

```
something match {
    case "val" => "default"
    case default@_ => smth(default)
}
```

Comment: For those like me who'd either never seen or forgotten this: see [Scala @ operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359014/scala-operator)