# Pattern matching on testing expected message

Tags: scala, akka

How can I test expected message with akka testkit if I don't know all message details? Can I use somehow underscore "_"?

Example I can test:

```
echoActor ! "hello world"
expectMsg("hello world")
```

Example i want to test

```
case class EchoWithRandom(msg: String, random: Int)

echoWithRandomActor ! "hi again"
expectMsg(EchoWithRandom("hi again", _))
```

The way i don't want to use:

```
echoWithRandomActor ! "hi again"
val msg = receiveOne(1.second)
msg match {
    case EchoWithRandom("hi again", _) => //ok
    case _ => fail("something wrong")
}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It doesn't look like you can do much about it, because `expectMsg` uses `==` [behind the scenes](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/67784dbdae3a627061b4b7c173db66f89774c9c8/akka-testkit/src/main/scala/akka/testkit/TestKit.scala#L348).

You could try to use [`expectMsgPF`](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/67784dbdae3a627061b4b7c173db66f89774c9c8/akka-testkit/src/main/scala/akka/testkit/TestKit.scala#L352-L368), where PF comes from `PartialFunction`:

```
echoWithRandomActor ! "hi again"
expectMsgPF() {
  case EchoWithRandom("hi again", _) => ()
}
```

#### Update

In recent versions (`2.5.x` at the moment) you need a [`TestProbe`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/testkit/TestProbe.html).

You can also return an object from the `expectMsgPF`. It could be the object you are pattern matching against or parts of it. This way you can inspect it further after `expectMsgPF` returns successfully.

```
import akka.testkit.TestProbe

val probe = TestProbe()

echoWithRandomActor ! "hi again"

val expectedMessage = testProbe.expectMsgPF() { 
    // pattern matching only
    case ok@EchoWithRandom("hi again", _) => ok 
    // assertion and pattern matching at the same time
    case ok@EchoWithRandom("also acceptable", r) if r > 0 => ok
}

// more assertions and inspections on expectedMessage
```

See [Akka Testing](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/testing.html) for more info.

Comment: Where does the `ok@` syntax come from?

Comment: @user6296589 it's called a pattern binder. There are SO questions about it, such as this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359014/scala-operator/2359365. The language specification deals with it here: https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/08-pattern-matching.html#pattern-binders