# Extract map from message received by actor

Tags: scala, akka

I have an actor which receives a map within a message. I would like to check the components of that map.

After looking here [Pattern matching on testing expected message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25287575/pattern-matching-on-testing-expected-message), I did this:

```
testReceiver.expectMsgPF() match {
      case SomeMessage(answer)  => {
        assert(answer.keys.size == 1)
        assert(answer.keys.head == "appId")
      }
      case _ => Failed
    }
```

However, I got this issue:

```
[error] You can make this conversion explicit by writing `expectMsgPF _` or `expectMsgPF(_,_)(_)` instead of `expectMsgPF`.
[error]     testReceiver.expectMsgPF() match {
[error]                             ^
```

After that, I changed the first line to:

```
testReceiver.expectMsgPF _ match {
```

After that, on the second line I get:

```
constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
[error]  found   : my.package.SomeMessage
[error]  required: (String, String) => PartialFunction[Any,Nothing] => Nothing
```

I think I'm not approaching this the right way.

How can I extract the map from the message and then check its properties?

Answer (score 1):

That curly-braced block it's actually a `PartialFunction` you are passing as the second parameter pf `expectMsgPF`. Therefore, no `match` is needed.

```
testReceiver.expectMsgPF() {
      case SomeMessage(answer)  => {
        assert(answer.keys.size == 1)
        assert(answer.keys.head == "appId")
      }
      case _ => Failed
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you specified a time limit? See the `expectMsgPF` method description from http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/testing.html:

> > expectMsgPF[T](d: Duration)(pf: PartialFunction[Any, T]): T
>
> Within the
>   given time period, a message must be received and the given partial
>   function must be defined for that message; the result from applying
>   the partial function to the received message is returned. **The duration
>   may be left unspecified** (empty parentheses are required in this case)
>   **to use the deadline from the innermost enclosing within block instead**.

Try to enclose your code in a `within` block:

```
  within(1000.millis) {
    testReceiver.expectMsgPF() match {
      case SomeMessage(answer)  => {
        assert(answer.keys.size == 1)
        assert(answer.keys.head == "appId")
      }
      case _ => Failed
    }
  }
```