# Meaning of ref@Ping in akka receive

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, akka, actor

I was surfing some code examples on akka and I found a particular example that I would like to be sure of the meaning:

`def receive: Receive = { 
    case original@Ping(x) => // do stuff
    case _ => //do stuff
}`

`Ping` is a case class used for message in the example.
But What's the meaning of that `original@` ? Is it the message sender? if so, is there any advantage of this approach over using the `sender` variable?

Sorry, but I can't give you the link because I can't find it anymore...

> Not sure if this Akka thing or just a advanced Scala pattern matching feature that I wasn't aware..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a Scala feature called `variable binding`. It binds the value being matched on to the variable. You can find more examples here [Scala @ operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359014/scala-operator)

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to find out is to try it:

```
case class Ping(x: Int)

scala> val msg = Ping(10)
msg: Ping = Ping(10)

scala> msg match {
     |    case original @ Ping(x) => {
     |        println("Original: " + original)
     |        println("x: " + x)
     |    }
     |    case _ => println("no match")
     | }
Original: Ping(10) // Printed the entire msg that was matched
x: 10              // Printed just the value x that was matched
```

So `original` is equivalent to `msg` which is `Ping(10)`. The `@` symbol lets you assign the entire matched object to an identifier.